# What is the secure method to enable cross-origin?

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I have a hosted API website and when I try to make an Ajax call I'm getting errors on the Chrome Console like:

> Failed to load `https://website.tld/api/FHoie83hrAFh3`: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

And

> Failed to load `https://website.tld/api/FHoie83hrAFh3`: Redirect from
>   '`https://website.tld/api/FHoie83hrAFh3`' to
>   '`https://website.tld/api/success`' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

After googling I found that I need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` after stating the `<?php` of the file `api.php`

I don't have any idea about this and I see there are some security issue if I use this.

What is the secure method to enable this for the API?

Comment: What is the php source code?

Comment: I used JSONP to cross domain xmlhttmpRequest. You don't need to provide fancy headers in PHP for that. just use JSONP beware It only uses GET type: More you can find here. [JSONP Reference](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

Comment: the only alternative to using * is to whitelist the domains which are allowed access. Don't forget this rule only applies to cross-domain ajax requests anyway, all other types of request are already allowed, unless you have other security mechanisms in place.

Comment: @SaadSuri I tried JSONP but the problem is I need to use POST

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to create php files on your side, that your ajax will call, and they would serve as proxy to the real API making curl to the API and returning the API response to the ajax call.